# Objective C - UICollectionViewController - using segues

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I am lost. I have a UICollectionViewController with 4 items, each of which has an imageView and an image. I am wanting to pass the image from a selected item to a view controller:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
      if (indexPath.item == 0)
      {
          [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"FinalFace" sender:self];
      }
  }

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
  {
       FinalViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
  }
```

Comment: andreamazz: Sorry I was not clear. How am I able to pass an image from the clicked item in the collection view to the FinalViewController. I do not understand how to get the indexPath.item of the clicked cell into the prepareForSegue method so that I may write: if (indexPath.item == int) followed by statements to pass data to the FinalViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either store the selected indexPath in a property, or use

```
[[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] firstObject]
```

to retrieve the selected cell. Once you have the cell you can access its imageView property, and pass its image to the FinalViewController (remember to create a public property on it).

Comment: andreamazz: Thanks so much for the help!! This, I am sure, will work.